# unix - distinct count, count and sum of values for all columns in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

given a file such as:

```
sid|storeNo|latitude|longitude
2|1|-28.03720000
9|2
10
jgn352|1|-28.03720000
9|2|fdjkjhn422-405
0000543210|gfdjk39
```

expected output:

```
sid|storeNo|latitude|longitude
543240|6|-56.0744|0|
6|5|3|0|
5|3|2|0|
```

I would like to return the count of values under each column, the count of distinct values under each column and then sum of all values under each column. But something must be wrong with my logic/syntax, any help correcting it would be great!

code so far (at the momemnt it returns no output):

```
    awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}
    NR==1{
            for(n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
               colname[n]=$n
            }
        }
    NR>1 { #skips header
    for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)
    {
        sum[j]+=$j
        rawcount[j]++
        #distinctcount[j, arr[j]]=1
    }
    }
    END{
    for(k=1;k<=NF;k++)
    {
    #for(i in distinctcount)
    # distinctcount[k, i]++
    print colname[j]"|"
print sum[j]"|"
print rawcount[j]"|"
print distinctcount[j]"|"
    }
    }' delimd2iffpipe.dat
```

Comment: All the things you're doing with your various scripts would be better done with a database (sqlite for instance, easily scriptable). The "sum" is not well defined with your sample - what do you do with entries that are not numbers? Are non-existent cells counted? If so are they all distinct or would 3 empty cells count as 1 in your distinct count, or 0?

Comment: @Mat -Sum will be adding only the numeric values, if a value has any non-numeric character in it then it won't be included in the sum. non-existent cells are not counted. ie 0 in the distinct count because it is an absence of a value.

Comment: Why are you attempting to do this with a text file and bash scripting? This is definitely something that would be better handled using a DB backend (sqlite or MySQL as suggested by Mat) and using a programming language like Python or Perl.

Comment: @toop: also, first get each of those three aggregates to work in three different scripts, that will be easier. Then combine them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution using `gawk`. **The script uses multidimensional arrays and I think it is only supported by the GNU version.**

Content of *script.awk* (with comments):

```
BEGIN {
        FS="|"
}

## Header.
NR==1{
        ## Get this number to know later how many columns to print.
        cols = NF;

        ## Print header.
        print

        ## Read next record.
        next
}

## Data.
NR>1 { 
    ## For each column, get sum, count and distinct count, save values in arrays.
    for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)
    {
        sum[j] += $j
        rawcount[j]++
        distcount[j][$j]++
    }
}

END{
        print_line(sum)
        print_line(rawcount)

        ## To print distinct count, for each column we count how many values exist in
        ## second dimension.
        for (i = 1; i <= cols; i++ ) {
                printf "%g|", length( distcount[i] ) ? length( distcount[i] ) : 0
        }
        print
}

func print_line(arr)
{
        for ( k = 1; k <= cols; k++ ) {
                printf "%g|", arr[k] ? arr[k] : 0
        }
        print

}
```

Run the script:

```
awk -f script.awk delimd2iffpipe.dat
```

Result:

```
sid|storeNo|latitude|longitude
543240|6|-56.0744|0|
6|5|3|0|
5|3|2|0|
```

---

**EDIT**: A workaround to avoid multidimensional arays. I substitute it with a subscript array. It's processing is more complex but I hope it works with all versions of `awk`:

Here the code. The result in my machine is the same as with previous script.

```
BEGIN {
        FS="|"
}

## Header.
NR==1{
        ## Get this number to know later how many columns to print.
        cols = NF;

        ## Print header.
        print

        ## Read next record.
        next
}

## Data.
NR>1 { 
        ## For each column, get sum, count and distinct count, save values in arrays.
    for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)
    {
        sum[j] += $j
        rawcount[j]++
        distcount[j, $j]++
    }
}

END{
        print_line(sum)
        print_line(rawcount)

        for (combined_index in distcount) {
                split( combined_index, idx, SUBSEP )
                dcount[ idx[1] ]++;
        }
        print_line(dcount)
}

func print_line(arr)
{
        for ( k = 1; k <= cols; k++ ) {
                printf "%g|", arr[k] ? arr[k] : 0
        }
        print

}
```

Comment: line:23:         distcount[j][$j]++
                     ^ syntax error

Comment: @toop: Added an `awk` script substituting `gawk` specific multidimensional arrays with subscript arrays. I hope it works with your version.